# Create route Express.js and MySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am playing with Express.js and MySQL. I am trying to create a route in order to display data via API.

In my database, I have a price field and I am trying to display all properties in the a price range.

```
SELECT * FROM properties
WHERE price BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000;
```

In my model.js file I set up like this:

```
Property.findBy = (valueMin, valueMax, result) => {
  sql.query(`SELECT * FROM properties WHERE price BETWEEN ${valueMin} AND ${valueMax}`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    if (res.length) {
      console.log("No price: ", res[0]);
      result(null, res[0]);
      return;
    }
    result({ kind: "range" }, null);
  });
};
```

In my controller.js file

```
exports.findMaxi = (req, res) => {
  Property.findBy(req.params.valueMin, req.params.valueMax, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.kind === "not_found") {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Not found property for range ${req.params.valueMin} and ${req.params.valueMax}`
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error  found property for range " + req.params.valueMin + req.params.valueMax
        });
      }
    } else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

And finally, my routes:

```
 app.get("/properties/:valueMin&valueMax", propertis.findMaxi);
```

This route doesn’t work. I don’t know how to solve this problem. Can someone offer assistance?

Comment: Do i miss something? Where did you described you issue?

Comment: @elsololobo,I updated my question. My route doesn’t work and I don’t know why, I have limited knowledge because I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your route is like

```
 app.get("/properties/:valueMin&valueMax", propertis.findMaxi);
```

you'll only be able to pass 1 value and the other is the string "&valueMax", so you can't change the value of valueMax... for example, if you want to have valueMin = 100, the query is like `GET /properties/100&valueMax.`

So, each value you want to pass in this way, use ':' before each variable, like

```
app.get("/properties/:valueMin&:valueMax", propertis.findMaxi);
```

and a query like `//GET /properties/100&200` will work

But I think it's better to pass the variables as query params `GET /properties?min=100&max=200`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to pass min and max as query parameters.

```js
// GET /properties?min=10000&max=20000
console.log(req.query.min) // => '10000'
console.log(req.query.max) // => '20000'
```

The way you did is that you have one value that you can access with `req.params` and it is `valueMin&valueMax` (I don't think it is even valid to have a variable that contains `&` character).

You could have a route like `/properties/:min/:max` to access those two separately, or just use query parameters which is made for that purpose

Comment: Thank you, now when I try to run route: properties?min=10000&max=20000 it returns all properties.